# How to prove the interchange of integral and expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How to prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}{h(t)\mathbb{E}(I(X>t))dt}=\mathbb{E}(\int_{0}^{\infty}{h(t)I(X>t)dt})$.
Can I treat $h(t)$ as a constant respect to $X$? Then, directly get the result?

The point is I do not understand what $\mathbb{E}(\int_{0}^{\infty}{h(t)I(X>t)dt})$ is.

Comment: What are the hypotheses on $h$?

Comment: What are the integrability assumptions on $h$ and on $X$? Expectation is defined in terms of an integral over the probability space. Can you interchange the order of integration?

Comment: @ncmathsadist. $h$ is differentiable function from real positive number to real positive number

Comment: I don't understand your question. The integral has $X$, not $X_t$, and what is $T$?

Comment: @Math1000. revised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral $\int_0^\infty h(t)I(X>t)\,dt$ is a random variable, call it $Y$. The role of the indicator random variable $I(X>t)$ is to restrict the $t$-integration to the (random) interval $(0,X)$. In other words,
$$
Y(\omega) =\int_0^{X(\omega)} h(t)\,dt,
$$
for each sample point $\omega$ in the sample space. You are then forming the expectation of $Y$.  If $h$ takes only non-negative values, then Tonelli's theorem can be used to justify the change in order of expectation and integration (in $t$).

Comment: Can you tell more about changing the order by Tonelli's theorem? I did not see where I can use it.

Comment: Let me think for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks better now, and I think all requirements for switching the order of integration are satisfied. It seems you are assuming finite expectation of $X$. To get at your last line/question: $X$ is a random variable and thus $I(X>t)$ is a random variable (for each fixed $t$). It is either $1$ or $0$, and depends (randomly) on the value $X$ takes. Thus $\int_0^\infty h(t) I(X>t)dt$ is a random variable. The function $h(t) I(X>t)$ is going to be set to zero over a certain interval depending on what value $X$ takes, thus we don't know the value of the integral with certainty.